# Combining music prod, dialog editing, sfx and foley: what's everyone doing?

Tags: sound-design, pro-tools, midi, music, logic

Dave here, logic 9 and ten on intel mac.  My headache is,15 min+ session with various in-tempo music elements that need to lie on bar/beat grid, and interstitial dialog which needs tweaking, re-performing, and subtle timing changes. (demo for theatre work).  the only way I know to preserve timing in Logic is to draw tempo changes to bring (e.g.) two dialog phrases closer together.  This is cumbersome.  Pretty sure Protools will not help, as the bar/beat (looping, midi-addition, quantized) aspect is still necessary.  Any ideas welcome! - Dave

Comment: Could you clarify a little.  The pieces that are in-tempo, are they all the same tempo or does the tempo for different portions vary?  Do these pieces need to remain on the grid, or is the grid for the purpose of lining things up?  In what way would you 'draw tempo changes to bring two dialog phrases closer together'?  I'm not sure that I understand exactly what you are trying to do and in what ways you are struggling.  I'm fairly proficient with Logic, so I may be able to help if I come to better understand the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I follow your question 100%.  Is this to picture?  If so, and maybe even if not, I would bounce down my music to individual stems.  That way, the music's tempo changes, quantization, reverbs, eq's, and whatever else is already taken care of.  Then you can pull those stems into a session that has a constant "tempo" (framerate, if to picture).  As long as you place your stems to *start* at the correct spot, they will playback as you intended, with proper timing and changes.  You'll essentially only need to automate the volume at this point.  Then you can edit your DX, FX, and Foley around your cues as needed and mix.

My point being that it's not a typical workflow for a re-recording mixer to work out of a session that has tempo maps and timing changes, like one might use when editing music.  The session should be at a locked and constant framerate that's consistent with the video.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the original dialogue edit should be done with the musical timing in mind. Mostly, this is done using temp tracks that have equivalent tempo/timing. Dialogue will need to maintain lip-sync but music can be tweaked from a timing perspective.

My recommendation is to ensure that the dialogue edit fits with the timing first, then apply the music once the dialogue edit is correct.